# Node list element convert to String and cut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to convert this node list element to String and cut it to have only value "12803"

```
if (document.getElementById('sale_info_order_from').innerHTML.indexOf('JDG') != -1){
  document.getElementById("invoice_text").style.outline = "thick solid green";
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[onclick^=copyTextToClipboard]');

var element = elements[1];


console.log(element);
```

Result i have now is:

```
<span class="tip_trigger" data-original-title="Kopiuj do schowka" onclick="copyTextToClipboard('12803')">12803</span>
```

Comment: That value appears to be the innerText; have you tried `elements[1].innerText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the element's `innerText`; replace `var element = elements[1];` with `var element = elements[1].innerText;`

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value via `element.innerText` or `element.innerHTML`, depending on what values you may have. Ask yourself what you would want to do if the inner content of the tag would be a template. If you want to get it as HTML, then `innerHTML` should be your choice. Otherwise it's `innerText`.